# Implode function doesn't store data in database table

Tags: php, mysql, explode, implode

I am trying to store a string (like 1, 2, 3, ...) in my database table but the stored data is only 1 (I see just 1 in the table column instead of 1, 2, 3, ...).I want to post checkbox_id from a php form and to store these numbers on a table column (the number is depending on which checkboxes are checked and how many of them are checked also).

Here is the code:

```
<form action="insert.php" method="post"><div>
  <div class="feed-activity-list"><div style="border: 0.5px solid green; border-right-style:none;" class="input-group m-b"><span class="input-group-addon"> 
     <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" name="opt[]" value="'.$points.'"></span>
     <input type="hidden" name="opt2[]" value="'.$row_select4['id'].'"> </div></div>
```

Submit Button (outside the php echo) :

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-w-m btn-primary">ΕΞΑΡΓΥΡΩΣΗ</button> 
     </form>
```

insert.php :

```
if(isset($_POST['opt2'])){



    foreach ($_POST['opt2'] as $value) {
        $gift = $_POST['opt2'];   
        $sliced = array_slice($gift, 0, -1);
         $gift_id = implode(" ", $sliced);
            }

echo $gift_id;

  $stmt_insert = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO transactions (gift_id) VALUES (:gift_id)"));

$stmt_insert->bindParam(':gift_id', $gift_id);
$stmt_insert->execute();
```

Comment: `implode(" ",...)` should be `implode(",", ...)`, and no need to use the foreach here.

Comment: What is in `$_POST['opt2']`???

Comment: `<input type="hidden" name="opt2[]" value="'.$row_select4['id'].'">`.I want to post each number of checked ckeckboxes.Am I right?

Comment: so simply go with `$gift_id = implode(",", array_filter($_POST['opt2']));` and store the `$gift_id`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you post the checked box values as array, so you have some blank fields. you need to filter them, so use the array_filter.

```
$filter_arr = array_filter($_POST['opt2']);
$gift_id = implode(",", $filter_arr);
```

and store the `$gift_id` into the database, this is the string of checked ids.

Comment: I think it worked fine!Thanks a lot for giving me a solution!Regards!

Answer (score -1):

Please do implode using commas.

```
$gift_id = implode(",", $sliced);
```

Also Your code within foreach is incorrect. Use $value inside foreach.

```
foreach ($_POST['opt2'] as $value) {
            $gift = $value;   
            $sliced = array_slice($gift, 0, -1);
            $gift_id = implode(" ", $sliced);
            }
```

Comment: Now I store NULL value in the table column!